# post data with xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi guys I'm trying to delete a file with Ajax and I have this code:

functions.js:

```
function deleter(val){
var value = val.replace(".",",");
var del = new XMLHttpRequest();
del.addEventListener("load", completedelete, false);
del.open("POST","index.php?action=delete",true);
del.send("file="+value);
}
```

index.php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action']=="delete"){
if(!isset($_POST['file'])){
    echo("not set");
}
if(unlink($_POST['file'])){
    echo"1";
}else{
    echo"0";
}
}
```

and I always get "not set" in the response with the 0 .

any one can help me?

Comment: **DANGER** you are in dire need of some sanity checking on that input! What if someone submitted `file=index.php`?

Comment: don't worry man i got it handled this was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
del.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

before `del.send()`.